# How to disable Chrome's right-click menu in a specific website?

Tags: google-chrome

I'm making some games in Scratch (https://scratch.mit.edu/) and i have this annoying thing in Chrome Browser: whenever i right-click with my mouse on the working area, the right-click browser menu pops up. This is normal in most cases, but not in Scratch. It doesn't let me work properly because it veils my project area.

Is there a way to disable it?

(In Microsoft Edge or Explorer there's no such problem)

Comment: What you have may well be the opposite, that chrome is blocking the website capturing the right click. Do you have any extensions that might be blocking that? https://www.google.com/search?&q=javascript+disable+right+click+chrome

Comment: This would be better on Stack Overflow